# error in Firebase connection in android Gradle library

Tags: java, android

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

1. List item

   ```
   private  void setUpFirebaseAuth(){
       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

          @Override
          public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
              FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

              // check the user is login
              checkCurrentUser(user);
              if(user != null){
                 // user is login
              }else {
                  // user signed out
              }

          }
      };
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you post your error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the error is and what you've tried already to solve the error. Also, consider posting **relevant** code snippets and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)